# How do I target an element nested inside a list item when the previous list item is clicked with Jquery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an un-ordered list like this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a class="foo" id="one">some text</a></li>
   <li><a class="foo" id="two">some text</a></li>
   <li><a class="foo" id="three">some text</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I need is to change the color of the left border of id 'three' if id 'two' is clicked. I know I can do something like this:

```
function leftHighlight(e){
if (e.target.id == 'two')
{
    $('#three').addClass('leftBorder');
    $('#one').removeClass('leftBorder');
    $('#two').removeClass('leftBorder');

}
```

and so on for each, but the Jquery gets very long when I have a long list of list items. Is there a more concise way of doing this? Everything I've seen online is for sibling selectors but since each `<a>` tag is not a sibling of the other I can't seem to figure out how to target it.

Also I need to have the `<a>`  inside the `<li>`  for accessibility/tabbing reasons.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what will happenif you click on `id` one or three?

Comment: What's the underlying logic of changing the left border of id "three" when "two" is clicked?

Comment: @brk if you click id one then the left border of id should change colour.

Comment: @jo8691 It's a design spec that the client asked for. They want a crazy navigation menu.

Comment: @Jthunter24 its not clear , `left border of id should change colour.`  you meant to say left border of next id?

Comment: @brk it says ```left border of id 3``` but yes I need the left border of the next id to change colour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `next()` like this. It gets the next sibling of the element selected.

https://api.jquery.com/next/

Edit : if you want the `a` to have the `leftBorder` class then you can use `closest`, `next` and `find` to target the next `a`.

`closest` get me the first element that match the `li` clicked. `next` the `li` which is just following and then `find` to get the `a` element inside the `li`.

```js
$('.foo').click(function(){
  $('a').removeClass('leftBorder');
  $(this).closest('li').next('li').find('.foo').addClass('leftBorder');
});
```

```css
.leftBorder {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
   <li><a class="foo" id="one">some text</a></li>
   <li><a class="foo" id="two">some text</a></li>
   <li><a class="foo" id="three">some text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I need the ```<a>``` to receive the class and change the border not the ```<li>```

Comment: @Jthunter24 Ok, I've changed my solution

Comment: That's weird, I target all a element with $('a').removeClass('leftBorder')

Comment: I had a spelling mistake on my end. You were right all along!

Comment: @Jthunter24 Ok perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `next()` method (https://api.jquery.com/next/) in combination with the `parent()` (https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method

`$(e.target).parent().next().children('a').addClass('leftBorder')`

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. I so wanted it to!

Comment: You may need to use `closest('li')` instead of `parent()` here. It's possible that the `<li>` element receives the click event instead of the `<a>` tag.

Comment: maybe it's the '$(this)' you pass the element as a parameter in the function, try the editted code

Answer (score 0):

As OP allowed for pure JavaScript to be used, here is 
a working (if lengthy) JS snippet:

```js
const ids = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('ul li .foo'));
// change selector to more specific if your HTML has more ul elements
const ul = document.querySelector('ul'); 

ul.addEventListener('click', function ulEventListener(ev) {

  let indexToHi = null;
  ids.forEach(function highlightLeft(el, ii) {

    if (indexToHi === null && el.id === ev.target.id) {
      indexToHi = ++ii;
      el.classList.remove('leftBorder') ;

    } else if (indexToHi !== null && ii === indexToHi) {
      el.classList.add('leftBorder') ;

    } else {
      el.classList.remove('leftBorder') ;
    };

  });

});
```

HTML, changed link text to provide clear reference to id.

```html
<ul>
   <li><a class="foo" id="zero">id zero</a></li>
   <li><a class="foo" id="one">id one</a></li>
   <li><a class="foo" id="two">id two</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.leftBorder {
  border-left : 2px solid red;
}
```

This is my first post, so I greet everyone and humbly accept all criticism and comments from more experienced forum members.